# SAS: Transform Transpose or SQL?

Tags: sql, sas, transpose

I have one more quick question.  I currently have a rather large data set that looks like the following:

```
Rank  Count  Score
1      100    10
Romeo & Juliet .  .
Shakespeare .  .
```

I need to somehow maintain the rank, count, and score ( 1, 100, 10) and create a new column for the name of the book and another column for the author.

Is there a good way to do this in SAS?  I'm drawing a blank and any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make sense.

Comment: Explain your problem further. Is said large data set a text file or current SAS data set? What do you have and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: That's exactly what the data I received looks like and why I need to transform it in a way that looks like this:
Rank  Count  Score  Title  Author

Reeza - the data is a csv which I imported into SAS to make into a dataset I can actually use.

Comment: It sounds like you're dealing with having multiple lines for a single record. It would help if you posted more example data. I'm sure it's clear to you, but I'm not seeing the full picture as yet.

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002001051.htm

Answer (score 1):

First off, before I give my answer, the key to getting specific answers is to ask a precise and detailed question.

From your imprecise question and the comments, I think I pieced together your problem. In fact, it's one I've encountered in the past.

You said in the comments that the data was in a csv file, but your example seems to show the data after your attempted import. From your description, a single observation is spread across 3 lines of data in the csv. I assume the data looks like so (I made up a second obs):

```
1,100,10
Romeo & Juliet
Shakespeare
2,90,9
The Old Man and the Sea
Hemingway
```

Here's the data step to read the file as structured.

```
data books;
infile '/folders/myfolders/books.csv' dlm=',' n=3 truncover;
input rank score count #2 book $50. #3 author $30.;
run;
```

First, let me explain the options on the `infile` statement. The option `n=3` specifies that 3 lines of input data are available in the input buffer which corresponds with the number of lines needed to compose a single obs. We'll exploit this option in the `input` statement. The `truncover` option ensures that SAS does not continue to read beyond the end of line for variables that have values shorter than the specified length. For instance, this option allows me to assign a 50 char length informat to the book title, even though the book titles were quite a bit shorter than that.

Let's move on to the `input` statement. Nothing special is needed to read rank, score and count since the first line of each 3-line group is standard, comma-delimited data. The `#2` notation tells SAS to move to the 2nd line of the 3-line group to read the book title. Of course, `#3` moves the line pointer to the last line of the 3-line group to read the final variable author.

Here's what the final output looks like:

[image]